# how to use javascript timer in a nested repeater?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, timer

I'm trying to add a javascript timer for products, if the item have a promotion then show the timer and start the count down.. so what i'm doing is im sending the end date from code behind to the javascript function and the function creates the timer based on the end date. I've been trying for long time the script is working, the issue is i'm not able to loop inside the nested repeater to get the correct countdown control id and index.
hope you guys can help me with this issue.
thanks

HTML Code:

```
        <asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="Repeater1" OnItemDataBound="rptdep_ItemDataBound" OnItemCommand="rptdep_Details_Command">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:LinkButton class="navbar-brand" runat="server" ID="LinkButton1" Style="text-decoration: none; margin-right: -25px; border: none; font-size: medium" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("department_code") %>' CommandName="more">
                <asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="rptdeppromo" OnItemDataBound="rptdeppromo_ItemDataBound" OnItemCommand="Item_depPromo_Command">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <div runat="server" id="countdown" class="cntdwn"></div>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:Repeater>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
```

Timer JS code:

```
function producttimer(compntname, enddate1, col) {
        $(document).ready(function () {

            var $countdown = $('#rptdep_rptdeppromo_' + compntname + '_countdown_' + col);


                // set the date we're counting down to
                var target_date = new Date(enddate1);
                // variables for time units
                var days, hours, minutes, seconds;

                // update the tag with id "countdown" every 1 second
                setInterval(function () {
                    target_date.getTime();

                    // find the amount of "seconds" between now and target
                    var current_date = new Date().getTime();

                    // check for match
                    if (current_date === target_date) {
                    }

                    var seconds_left = (target_date - current_date) / 1000;

                    // do some time calculations
                    days = parseInt(seconds_left / 86400);
                    seconds_left = seconds_left % 86400;

                    hours = parseInt(seconds_left / 3600);
                    seconds_left = seconds_left % 3600;

                    minutes = parseInt(seconds_left / 60);
                    seconds = parseInt(seconds_left % 60);

                    // format countdown string + set tag value
                    $countdown.text(days + "days, " + hours + "hrs, " + minutes + "min, " + seconds + "s");
                }, 1000);
        }); //EOF DOCUMENT.READY
    }
```

C# parent repeater code:

```
protected void rptdep_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{

    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {
        Repeater innerRepeater2 = (Repeater)e.Item.FindControl("rptdeppromo");
        DataRowView drv = (DataRowView)(e.Item.DataItem);

        }
    }
}
```

C# nested repeater code:

```
protected void rptdeppromo_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {
        DataRowView drv = (DataRowView)(e.Item.DataItem);

DateTime EndDate = Convert.ToDateTime(Convert.ToDateTime(drv.Row["publishtdt"]).ToString("dd MMM yyyy"));


        int countw = 0;
        int count = 0;

        if (total < 30)
        {
            count += 1;
            foreach (RepeaterItem item in rptdep.Items)
            {
                countw += 1;
            }
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, this.GetType(), "counter" + countw, "producttimer('" + countw + "','" + EndDate + "', '" + e.Item.ItemIndex + "');", true);
        }
        else
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is a different approach:

1- in your repeater, display all Promotions End date in label, and give them the same class "cntdwn"

2- your JS , when the page is ready it will look all items in your page with the same class and loop inside them:

```
      var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("cntdwn");
      for (var i = 0, len = elements.length; i < len; i++) 
        {
         var PromoID = elements[i].Id;
         Var EndDate  = document.getElementById(PromoID).textContent;
        }
```

3- Now you have the Lable ID , and The end Date , use your countdown logic to display the countdown in the text area of that ID.

Good luck ...

Comment: It worked, just added some tweaks to the script.. thanks man.. cheers

Answer (score 0):

the upvoted answer worked for me, but i needed to tweak it a bit. I thought some code may help the next person who looks here. 
using the plugin jquery.countup.js (any counter should work):

```
<div id="div<%# ((RepeaterItem)Container).ItemIndex + 1%>"  class="countdown">
     <%# Eval("EntryDate") %>
</div>


<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('countdown');
        var len = elements.length;
        for (var i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
            var timerID = elements[i].id;
            var startDate = elements[i].innerText;
            startCounter(startDate, timerID);
        };
    });

    function startCounter(entryDate, timerID) {
        var entDate = new Date(entryDate);
        var year = (entDate).getFullYear();
        var month = (entDate).getMonth() + 1;
        var day = (entDate).getDate();
        var hour = (entDate).getHours();
        var min = (entDate).getMinutes();
        var sec = (entDate).getSeconds();

        $("#" + timerID).empty();
        $("#" + timerID).countup({
            start: new Date(year, month, day, hour, min, sec) //year, month, day, hour, min, sec
        });
    };
```

Comment: please note what you had to do differently.

Comment: actually, i didn't really do much differently, but it took me awhile to find out how to put an item index on the repeater.  I thought the next person might benefit from the full code as opposed to the partial.